# searchkit - how to pass props into an itemComponent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, searchkit

I'm fairly new to React and I would really appreciate some help on this, as its been driving me nuts.

I am trying to figure out how I can pass props into searchkit's `listComponent` from the `<ViewSwitcherHits/>` component.

**Parent Component:**

```
<ViewSwitcherHits 
hitComponents={[
    {key:"query", title:"Query", listComponent:QueryDetailView, defaultOption:true}
]}
/>
```

So the `QueryDetailView` is a custom Component I created that requires props in order to show a detail view of a selected query. The user selects a query block from a dropdown in another Component, and that selected filter would then display in the `QueryDetailView` Component. There may be a better way to pass that selected query object from a child to the parent back down to the `QueryDetailView` child. I come from Angular so I know a service would be perfect for this, but not sure how to implement in React. Or if Searchkit even allows passing in props into an `ItemComponent`.

I hope this is enough information. If not, please let me know and I will add more code. Thanks!

Comment: You can pass child to a component like that: <AwesomeComponent><QueryDetailView /></AwesomeComponent>. You can access to this component in AwesomeComponent by using this.props.children. If you want add props to this.props.children, do something like that:  {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { loggedIn: this.state.loggedIn })}

Comment: So AwesomeComponent acts as a wrapper to QueryDetailView? Could you show a more fleshed out example of the React.cloneElement?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the QueryDetailsView with your properties to a variable/constant and then use that as the listComponent. The searchkit properties and your properties will be merged, so inside the QueryDetailsView you will be able to access this.props.oneprop and this.props.anotherprop:

```
const qdv = (<QueryDetailView oneprop="somevalue" anotherprop="anothervalue" />);

<ViewSwitcherHits 
hitComponents={[
    {key:"query", title:"Query", listComponent:qdw, defaultOption:true}
]}
/>
```